# Waiting for a single Shell script in a series of scripts to run to completion before continuing (Java, MySQL, JUnit)

Tags: java, mysql, shell, junit

I'm working on a Java program that incorporates Process and Runtime to run several shell scripts for automated testing. All but one of these scripts runs fine, which causes an issue with script calls following it. Ex:

```
process = runtime.exec("A.sh");
process = runtime.exec("B.sh");
process = runtime.exec("C.sh");
```

A.sh runs fine and only takes a few seconds to run. B.sh, however, takes a couple minutes to run, and I think this is causing a problem with running C.sh, since they both interact with the same MySQL table and the overlap causes a Communications Link Failure.

Without overloading you with unnecessary information, my question is, *how can I wait to ensure a run shell script has been run to completion/termination before moving on to the next exec() call?*

What I've tried:

```
process.waitFor()
```

This doesn't work, I don't think it waits until the script is completely done

```
process.wait(long time_period)
```

This doesn't work since it causes the current thread to wait which results in the remaining shell script calls to get skipped and the next test case to begin prematurely.

The shell script I call that causes the problem is *not* a simple script, but I didn't write it myself and have little understanding of what it does behind the scenes. The only relevant information I have about it is that it directly connects to the MySQL database in question whereas my program uses java.sql.* to (I believe) remotely connect (although it is a local database on a remote machine).

Edit:

After following a suggestion, I've looked into the Apache Commons Exec and tried a new strategy, unsuccessfully.

```
ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(300000); //For five minutes
CommandLine cmdline = CommandLine.parse("./directory/shell.sh");
DefaultExecutor executor = setExitValue(0);
executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
int exitVal = executor.execute(cmdLine);
//A line to log the exit val in another file
```

My log gives no implication that the shell script was actually run, as the time between a logged statement saying "shell.sh begins" and "test 2 starts" are essentially the same instant, which means the ~2 minute process that shell.sh runs never happens. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: what about checking the exit status of the shell scripts?

Comment: I haven't tried that nor do I know how, can you suggest a page that would helpful for learning how that works? Tutorial or otherwise, no preference.

Comment: I was referring to [this](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/Process.html#exitValue()) But I believe that Vadim's answer provides a better solution to your problem.

Comment: If you want to run them sequentially, create a new sh-script that just run them each after each other. Then run that from java.

Comment: I would do that but there are other file manipulation calls I need to make in between them. Essentially I could make one sh script that handles everything but due to the complexity of our back-end systems I can't really simplify the process that much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I use [Apache Commons Exec](http://commons.apache.org/exec/tutorial.html). Have synchronous and asynchronous execution support. Execution timeout can be set.

First paragraph from their tutorial page:

> At this point we can safely assume that you would like to start some
>   subprocesses from within your Java application and you spent some time
>   here to do it properly. You look at Commons Exec and think "Wow -
>   calling Runtime.exec() is easy and the Apache folks are wasting their
>   and my time with tons of code". Well, we learned it the hard way (in
>   my case more than once) that using plain Runtime.exec() can be a
>   painful experience. Therefore you are invited to delve into
>   commons-exec and have a look at the hard lessons the easy way ...

Advanced usage example (some code is missing like BusinessException and "StreamUtil.closeQuietly", but it could be easily replaced):

```
    ExecuteWatchdog watchdog = new ExecuteWatchdog(EXECUTION_TIMEOUT_IN_MS);
    DefaultExecutor executor = new DefaultExecutor();

    executor.setWatchdog(watchdog);
    executor.setExitValue(0);

    ByteArrayOutputStream outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    ByteArrayOutputStream errorStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

    executor.setStreamHandler(new PumpStreamHandler(outputStream, errorStream));

    try {
        log.info(commandLine.toString());

        int exitCode = executor.execute(commandLine, (Map<?, ?>) null);

        if (exitCode != 0)
            throw new BusinessException("Process exited with non-zero exit code.");

        return outputStream.toString();
    } catch (ExecuteException e) {
        String errorStreamStr = null;

        if (errorStream.size() != 0)
            errorStreamStr = errorStream.toString();

        StringBuilder errorMessageBuilder = new StringBuilder();

        errorMessageBuilder.append("main.error").append(":\n").append(
                e.getMessage()).append("\n\n");

        if (errorStreamStr != null) {
            errorMessageBuilder.append("additional.error").append(":\n").append(errorStreamStr).append("\n\n");
        }

        errorMessageBuilder.append("command.line").append(":\n").append(commandLine.toString());

        if (log.isDebugEnabled())
            log.debug(errorMessageBuilder.toString());

        throw new BusinessException(errorMessageBuilder.toString());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        throw new IllegalStateException(e);
    } finally {
        StreamUtil.closeQuietly(outputStream, errorStream);
    }
```

Comment: This may be a stupid question but will this work in a Unix system? I'm only asking since I see a lot of CommandLine (which I'm not familiar with).

Comment: Check this [test matrix](http://commons.apache.org/exec/testmatrix.html). My code (based on Commons Exec) was tested to work on Windows, MacOS and Enterprise RedHat.

Comment: So I gave this a shot, but I feel as if I may messed something up. I've edited the original post to contain the new code.

Comment: I posted code example with advanced error processing, cause I think, that your error message could be printed to output or error stream.

Comment: Thanks! This is really useful and definitely points me in the right direction. I think I know where to go from here.